# Get oldest records with a criteria based on id

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get all oldest records based on an id (here : `External Id`)

**Data**

```
Row | Id  | External Id | Date                | Status
1   | 100 | 5000        | 2020-10-18 12:00:58 | F
2   | 101 | 5000        | 2020-10-16 14:10:01 | F
3   | 102 | 5000        | 2020-11-19 05:00:54 | P
4   | 103 | 5998        | 2021-01-08 13:22:11 | P
5   | 104 | 1230        | 2020-08-06 11:11:07 | F
6   | 105 | 1230        | 2020-08-08 18:19:52 | P
```

**Expected result**

```
Row | Id  | External Id | Date                | Status
2   | 101 | 5000        | 2020-10-16 14:10:01 | F
4   | 103 | 5998        | 2021-01-08 13:22:11 | P
5   | 104 | 1230        | 2020-08-06 11:11:07 | F
```

However, I dont know how to build this request. A sub request is needed? Can you please help me?

Thank you, regards

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the tag `Oracle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [ROW_NUMBER() function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY External_id ORDER BY "Date") rn
    FROM YourTable
) a
WHERE a.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can row_number analytic function to rank your rows first, then filter out those rows whose rank = 1. It is necessary to put your column names "Row" and "Date" between double quotes.

```sql
select "Row", ID, EXTERNAL_ID, "Date", STATUS
from (
select t.*, row_number()over(partition by EXTERNAL_ID order by "Date")rank 
from your_table t
)
where rank = 1
order by "Row"
;
```